# Replace Data in CSV File with data from nslookup using python

Tags: python

So basically I have a CSV file setup like this:

```
IP or HostName, Device Name,  Device Description
10.10.10.10,    Device A,     Firewall
10.10.10.11,    Device B,     Firewall
10.10.10.12,    Device C,     Firewall
VBHOST12C,      Device D,     VM
```

I need to correct this list so that the hostname is replaced with an IP. I figured I would have Python open the csv, then utilize nslookup for the lines where there is a hostname instead of an IP, and replace them with that IP, and output it to a new corrected csv. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is commonly called a "ping sweep" and googling for the term PythonPingSweeper came back with a ton of hits.

I found this online, I would  be lying if I claimed I wrote it, I do what you're looking for in old DOS Batch but Python aint my thing:

If I'm breaking some rules of courtesy be appending the script here then complain in silence since those are the same people that usually gripe about single line URL responses without context.

https://gist.github.com/4404340

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import subprocess
import socket


class CannotResolve(Exception):
  pass


def resolve(host):
  start = time.time()
  try:
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
  except Exception, e:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise CannotResolve("Cannot resolve %s: %s" % (host, e))
  else:
    end = time.time()
    return (ip, (end-start)*1000)


def ping(host):
  cmd = ['ping', '-c', '1', host]
  start = time.time()
  try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    so, se = p.communicate()

  except Exception:
    # On error, return 0
    print "Error running %s" % cmd
    print "stderr:\n%s" % se
    return 0

  else:
    end = time.time()
    return (end-start)*1000


class Connection(object):
  def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

  def connect(self):
    retries = 10

    for x in range(retries):
      try:
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect( (self.host, self.port) )

      except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "Retry %s" % (x+1)
        time.sleep(1)
      else:
        return True

      print "Giving up after %s attempts" % retries

  def send(self, msg):
    print "Send: %r" % msg
    self.connect()
    retries = 10
    for x in range(retries):
      try:
        self.sock.sendall(msg)
      except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "Retry %s" % (x+1)
        time.sleep(1)
      else:
        return True
    print "Giving up after %s attempts" % retries


def main():
  delay = 1

  hosts = ["google.com", "stackoverflow.com"]

  conn = Connection('127.0.0.1', 2003)
  while True:
    for h in hosts:
      now = int(time.time())

      hostname = socket.gethostname()

      print "Resolving %s" % h
      try:
        ip, speedms = resolve(h)
      except CannotResolve, e:
        print "Cannot resolve", e
        # Zero values
        conn.send(
          "pings.%s.dns_%s %s %d\n" % (
            hostname, h.replace(".", "_"), 0, now))
        conn.send(
          "pings.%s.ping_%s %s %d\n" % (
            hostname, h.replace(".", "_"), 0, now))

        continue # Next host

      else:
        conn.send(
          "pings.%s.dns_%s %s %d\n" % (
            hostname, h.replace(".", "_"), speedms, now))


      now = int(time.time())
      print "Pinging %s (%s)" % (ip, h)
      p = ping(h)
      print "done"

      conn.send(
        "pings.%s.ping_%s %s %d\n" % (
          hostname, h.replace(".", "_"), p, now))

      time.sleep(delay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but a pingsweep is not what I am attempting. I would utilize a pingsweep if I was trying to discover onlines hosts, services, etc. I am not, I already have a list of devices in a csv file. I need this all to be output in the same format to a csv file, and replace the hostnames, with their corresponding IPs, while leaving the IPs already listed alone.

Comment: gotcha,  are you opposed to using a for/if command to getting it done right now ?  Assuming your lines have parity and line #8433 in both files is the same, and all the data fits into the same column,  you might already know you can do this in one line or less in a command shell.

Answer (score 0):

To convert hostname in the first column in given files (or stdin) to ip  and print the result to stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import fileinput
import socket
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

def ip(row):
    try:
        row[0] = socket.gethostbyname(row[0])
    except EnvironmentError:
        pass # return row as is if can't resolve address
    return row

def main():
    pool = Pool(20) # use concurrent connections
    rows = pool.imap(ip, csv.reader(fileinput.input()))
    csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(rows)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```