# Pandas: Performing nslookup on a CSV field, then writing the hostname to another column

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I'm trying to perform a nslookup within a CSV file if the Computer Name field has a value of unknown31 (the tailing number is different for each unknown hostname), I have the IP address in a separate column. The nslookup hostname should populate the applicable Computer Name cell in the CSV. It doesn't seem to even execute the nslookup, as the script finishes in 5 seconds on a csv with ~100 systems identified as "unknown" for the Computer Name column.

This question is nearly exact to what I need (not the first answer, but the authors comment), but it doesn't appear the user returned with a solution:
[Replace Data in CSV File with data from nslookup using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330366/replace-data-in-csv-file-with-data-from-nslookup-using-python)

Here is the applicable code so far, am I not iterating or writing to csv properly?:

```
# Find hostname by the IP address, if host name value is "unknown"

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Computer Name"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["IP Address"])
for name, row in pcname.iteritems():
    if str(name).startswith("unknown"):
        retip = socket.gethostbyipaddr(df1)
#        os.system('nslookup {0}'.format(df1)
        csv.writer(retip).writerows(df)
```

Comment: gethostbyipaddr returns the "looked up" name. you never capture that return value, so basically your dns lookups are useless. "go fetch me a shrubbery and throw it in the garbage".

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for that, changed that to 'retip = socket.gethostbyipaddr(df1)' and the bottom part to 'csv.writer(retip).writerows(df)'. Still not getting anything written, am I iterating through the dataframes correctly (updated code).

Comment: make sure those ips actually have reverse dns mappings, too. not all IPs do.

Comment: @MarcB Confirmed that a majority do, performed manual nslookups on various ones and got a return of their hostname. Should I stick to gethostbyipaddr or nslookup?